# Retrieve Keys/Values from OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES

Tags: java, open-telemetry

When using Opentelemetry java, is there a way to get the keys and values from OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES?

I found HostResource, OsResource, etc. but can't find how to get the custom attributes. How are the values being added to the logs and traces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `ResourceConfiguration#createEnvironmentResource()` newly added in 1.28.0 (https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/pull/5554)